# Allocating resources based on a priority

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I want to create `assign` column based on `rank` and `limit` by `group`.
In particular, for each group, I have a priority rank (e.g., 1,2,3 or 1,3,6 or 3,4,5 etc). Based on the rank (the small number is a priority), I want to allocate the resource given in `limit` column. Now I am doing this by hand. But I want to express this exercise using `tidyverse`. How do I allocate by `mutate` and `group_by`(or other methods)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`, you can use `top_n` after grouping. This will filter the top values based on `rank` - where the n to keep in each group is determined by `limit`. Those kept will be assigned 1, and then merged with your original data.

Let me know if this provides the desired result.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  top_n(limit[1], desc(rank)) %>%
  mutate(assign = 1) %>%
  right_join(df) %>%
  replace_na(list(assign = 0)) %>%
  arrange(group, rank)
```

**Output**

```
   group  rank limit assign
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A         1     1      1
 2 A         2     1      0
 3 A         3     1      0
 4 B         1     1      1
 5 B         3     1      0
 6 B         6     1      0
 7 C         3     2      1
 8 C         4     2      1
 9 C         5     2      0
10 C         6     2      0
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "C"), rank = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6), limit = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```